# How do I download a specific version of a package on git.centos.org?

Tags: centos, fedora, git

I am browsing [**this page**](https://git.centos.org/tree/rpms!glib2/5f79824ad8c41866133f7797b158e8a9e9efc986),  looking for source or binary for `glib2-2.42.2-5.el7`. (I got there from [**here**](https://git.centos.org/log/rpms!glib2/refs!heads!c7)) It seems like this is a patch rather than the entire source.

Where can I get either the complete source or binary for a specific package from centos.org?

Answer (score 2):

Yes , it is a patch for `glib2` version : `2.42.2` .

You can download the `rpm` of `glib2-2.42.2-5.el7` from [here](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/31978518/dir/centos_7/com/glib2-2.42.2-5.el7.x86_64.rpm.html):

```
wget ftp://bo.mirror.garr.it/1/slc/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/Packages/glib2-2.42.2-5.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

The source (`glib2-2.42.2-5.el7.src.rpm`) can be download as follow :

```
wget ftp://bo.mirror.garr.it/1/slc/centos/7.1.1503/updates/Source/SPackages/glib2-2.42.2-5.el7.src.rpm
```

You can use `yumdownloader glib2` to download the `glib2-2.46.2-4.el7` ( but it dosn't answer your question)